# Eagerly fetch child when loading parent

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data Jpa and Hibernate is the provider.

I have a Parent class mapped as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
public class Parent {

    private List<Child> childs;
    private List<AnotherChild> anotherChilds;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Child> getChilds() {
        return childs;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<AnotherChild> getAntoherChilds() {
        return anotherChilds;
    }

}
```

and child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="child")
public class Child {

    private Parent parent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "column_name")
    public Parent getParent() {
        return patern;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name="another_child")
public class AnotherChild {

    private Parent parent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "column_name")
    public Parent getParent() {
        return patern;
    }

}
```

- When I load the parent from the database, it doesn't load the list of
  child immediately and
- When I call parent.getChilds(), it returns
  null.

Can you give some advice? Am I wrong anywhere? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

After some research, I realize that when I have only single child, it loaded eagerly (like it should). But when I have multiple child, it doesn't - even though it has been marked FetchType.EAGER and the other FetchType.LAZY.

Note: If I marked both as FetchType.EAGER, it'll throws MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags.

The same happened when I annotate it using @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)

Comment: Try adding the Entity annotation with the table name for both classes

Comment: Actually it was already an entity. I have updated my question.

Comment: If you are open to using Hibernate-specific annotations, you can add `@org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.JOIN)` to the one-to-many field.  This will force Hibernate to load the children with the parent.

Comment: No need for hibernate specific annotations here in my opinion. It should load the children eagerly. Can you give us your persistence.xml maybe something is wrong there, since your code looks pretty OK to me

Comment: @manish: Yes, when I have only single child it works. But I have multiple childs (I have edited my question), and it doesn't loaded like it should.

Comment: @sashok_bg Yes, it works now. But the problem exists when I have more than 1 child.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you should be getting these errors.  Are you posting actual code?  Can you post a sample application that demonstrates the problem and that people can quickly run?

Comment: @dkakunsi change List to Set and it should be OK

Answer (score 2):

If added Entity annotation parent.getChilds() should not come empty.it would be better as you do Entity.

```
    @Entity 
    @Table(name="PARENT_TBL")
    public class Parent {
        //other fields
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE},orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<Child> childs;
        //getter setter        
    }


    @Entity 
    @Table(name="CHILD_TBL")
    public class Child {
     //other fields
      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
      private Parent parent;
    //getter setter

 }
```

Example Get Parent Query;

```
public Parent getParent(long parentId) throws Exception {
   session = sessionFactory.openSession();
       Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Parent.class, "parent");
        cr.setFetchMode('parent.childs', FetchMode.JOIN);
        cr.add( Restrictions.eq("parent.id", parentId));
        Parent parent = cr.uniqueResult();
        tx = session.getTransaction();
        session.beginTransaction();
        tx.commit();
    return parent;
```

EAGER loading of collections means that they are fetched fully at the time their parent is fetched. So if you have Parent and it has  List, all the childs are fetched from the database at the time the Parent is fetched.

LAZY on the other hand means that the contents of the List are fetched only when you try to access them. For example, by calling parent.getChilds().iterator(). Calling any access method on the List will initiate a call to the database to retrieve the elements. This is implemented by creating a Proxy around the List (or Set). So for your lazy collections, the concrete types are not ArrayList and HashSet.

Comment: I need the child when parent is loaeded. because, session will be closed after that.

Comment: Added getParent() query.

Comment: Thanks for the query, @jackk. But I actually using Spring Data JPA and I'm trying to not using additional Session Management. So, it would be nice if I can configure it in Entity mapping.